# Playwright/Chromium: Request stuck pending for localhost:8082

Tags: networking, windows-10, chromium, playwright

I just installed [Playwright](https://playwright.dev/) to create some automated tests for my web-app.

I got my test running fine on the staging version of my site just fine, but one of my requests is hanging when I try running it against localhost:

[image]

I have Nginx running on `:8080` and webpack running on `:8082` to serve my JS. As you can see, the document ("create") is served from `:8080` no problem, but `all.js` which is `http://localhost:8082/assets/all.js` never finishes.

What's really confusing me though is that I can load that URL in a new tab in Chrome just fine, I can `wget` under WSL, and I can `curl` it under `cmd.exe`. So there's something funky going on with the networking when the browser instance is created by Playwright, but I don't know how to debug further. The same thing happens if I set `defaultBrowserType: 'firefox'`.

[image]

What else can I try?

---

I just found `chrome://net-export/` and enabled it during the request. I've got all the CLI flags now:

```
    "clientInfo": {
      "cl": "b9c217c128c16f53d12f9a02933fcfdec1bf49af-refs/branch-heads/5195@{#176}",
      "command_line": "\"C:\\Users\\Mark\\AppData\\Local\\ms-playwright\\chromium-1019\\chrome-win\\chrome.exe\" --disable-field-trial-config --disable-background-networking --enable-features=NetworkService,NetworkServiceInProcess --disable-background-timer-throttling --disable-backgrounding-occluded-windows --disable-back-forward-cache --disable-breakpad --disable-client-side-phishing-detection --disable-component-extensions-with-background-pages --disable-default-apps --disable-dev-shm-usage --disable-extensions --disable-features=ImprovedCookieControls,LazyFrameLoading,GlobalMediaControls,DestroyProfileOnBrowserClose,MediaRouter,DialMediaRouteProvider,AcceptCHFrame,AutoExpandDetailsElement,CertificateTransparencyComponentUpdater,AvoidUnnecessaryBeforeUnloadCheckSync,Translate --allow-pre-commit-input --disable-hang-monitor --disable-ipc-flooding-protection --disable-popup-blocking --disable-prompt-on-repost --disable-renderer-backgrounding --disable-sync --force-color-profile=srgb --metrics-recording-only --no-first-run --enable-automation --password-store=basic --use-mock-keychain --no-service-autorun --export-tagged-pdf --no-sandbox --auto-open-devtools-for-tabs --deny-permission-prompts --allow-loopback-in-peer-connection --user-data-dir=\"C:\\Users\\Mark\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\playwright_chromiumdev_profile-5Cth57\" --remote-debugging-pipe --no-startup-window --flag-switches-begin --flag-switches-end --file-url-path-alias=\"/gen=C:\\Users\\Mark\\AppData\\Local\\ms-playwright\\chromium-1019\\chrome-win\\gen\"",
      "name": "Chromium",
      "official": "unofficial",
      "os_type": "Windows NT: 10.0.19044 (x86_64)",
      "version": "105.0.5195.19",
      "version_mod": ""
    },
```

And a few request details:

```
    {
      "params": {
        "headers": [
          "Host: localhost:8082",
          "Connection: keep-alive",
          "sec-ch-ua: \"Chromium\";v=\"105\", \"Not)A;Brand\";v=\"8\"",
          "Origin: http://localhost:8080",
          "Accept-Language: en-CA",
          "sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0",
          "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/105.0.0.0 Safari/537.36",
          "sec-ch-ua-platform: \"Windows\"",
          "Accept: */*",
          "Sec-Fetch-Site: same-site",
          "Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors",
          "Sec-Fetch-Dest: script",
          "Referer: http://localhost:8080/",
          "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br"
        ],
        "line": "GET /assets/all.js HTTP/1.1\r\n"
      },
      "phase": 0,
      "source": {
        "id": 170,
        "start_time": "131696227",
        "type": 1
      },
      "time": "131696228",
      "type": 169
    },
```

Nothing really jumps out at me as suspicious though.

Comment: Have you found the couse of your issue ?

Comment: @JulienKode No, but it works when I put it behind a proxy.

Comment: I am having the same issues atm. We have a frontend which makes requests to 2 different backends. It seems like all GET requests to one of the two backend get stuck in PENDING. Banging my head against the wall to why this happens...
Only happens when playwright is controlling the browser.